# Data not received correctly by TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I have a client-server program.

I'm sending data like this:

```
private void Sender(string s,TcpClient sock)
{
   try
   {
      byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
      sock.Client.Send(buffer);
   }catch{}
}
```

and on the client side receiving like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[PacketSize];
int size = client.Client.Receive(buffer);
String request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, size);
```

The problem is that data is not fully received always, sometimes it's only part of what I have sent. `PacketSize` is 10240 which is more than the bytes I send. I have also set SendBufferSize and ReceiveBufferSize at both sides.

The worst part is that sometimes data is fully received!

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `size` value returned by `TcpClient.Receive` is not the same as the length of the buffered string you sent. This is because there is no guarantee that when calling `Receive` once you will get back all the data that you sent with `Send` call. This behavior is intrinsic to the way TCP works (it's a stream-, not a message-based data protocol).

You cannot solve the problem by using bigger buffers, as the buffers you provide can only *limit* the amount of data that `Receive` returns. Even if you provide a 1MB buffer and there is 1MB of data to read, `Receive` can legitimately return any number of bytes (even just 1).

What you need to do is make sure that you have buffered all the data before calling `Encoding.GetString`. To do that, you need to know how much data there is in the first place. So at the very least, you need to write the length of the string bytes when sending:

```
  byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
  byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length);
  sock.Client.Send(length);
  sock.Client.Send(buffer);
```

When receiving, you will first read the length (which has a known fixed size: 4 bytes) and then start buffering the rest of the data in a temp buffer until you have `length` bytes (this might take any number of `Receive` calls, so you 'll need a `while` loop). Only then can you call `Encoding.GetString` and get your original string back.

**Explanation of the behavior you observe:**

Even though the network stack of the OS makes pretty much no guarantees, *in practice* it will usually give you the data one TCP packet brings with one `Receive` call. Since the MTU (maximum packet size) for TCP allows around 1500 bytes for payload, naive code will work fine as long as the strings are less than this size. More than that and it will get split into multiple packets, and one `Receive` will then return only part of the data.

Comment: +1. And dont forget to use a timeout on the tcp client/stream, otherwise your application will hang if the application who sends the data missbehaves/have network issues.

Comment: @stefan: It would be even better to use the `Async` methods instead. But let's get the basics right first :)

Comment: @Jon it can be better to use Async yes, but it really depends on the application.

Comment: Its a very good idea to have a start byte identifier too, to make sure your in-sync. So when you have read all the bytes your expecting, the very next byte should be a known value, followed by the next message (or EOF).

Comment: @FlappySocks: Why? TCP guarantees that data is received exactly as sent, or not at all. A magic marker may make you feel more confident, but is there a technical reason for it?

Comment: @Jon if the data is sent correctly from the client yes. And if the client is always up to date (using correct protocol). This is all a very toyish implementation, in the real world you would want to have markers for every data entry.

Comment: @stefan: In the real world you would want to have a proper message-based protocol with versioning, optional headers, etc on top of TCP. But *markers* are not needed to do that. TCP doesn't use markers. IP doesn't use markers. Why should you?

Comment: @Jon if you have proper versioning and headers etc then you prety much have the "markers" there ;)

Comment: @stefan: Maybe we don't disagree. It's simply that when I hear "marker" I think "magic value", and it's magic values that I believe gain you nothing.

Comment: @Jon By using markers/magic values you can build a very dynamic protocol that will allow for more feutures without updating old clients. Sometimes its good, sometimes its a very bad choice, really depends on the application. But nevertheless somehow you have to make sure the data you get is what you think it is. Whatever rocks your boat really :)

Comment: actually it's pretty big project and these code above (posted by me)
is run in thread and everything was working fine until I've sended 
big 2-3KB xml data